# How can I nest angular expressions?

Tags: angularjs

I want to do something similar to (in my html):

```
{{ Customer.Name }}
```

when **Customer.Name** is

```
"{{ Customer.FirstName + ' ' + Customer.LastName }}"
```

How can I achieve this? The **Customer.Name**-String is a dynamic configuration that I read from the server. I would like to do this on several places in my application so I don't want a static code-behind-function that does this for me.

All I want is that Angular evaluates the expression recursively.

Comment: There is no general way to do this. You'll need some kind of helper function (e.g. directive, filter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `$eval`() of `$scope` to achieve this.

For example, your Controller would define your customer object like this:

```
function TestCtrl ($scope) {
  $scope.customer = {
  firstname : 'Darth',
  lastname : 'Vader',
  name : 'customer.firstname + " " + customer.lastname'
 };
 $scope.ev = $scope.$eval;
```

}

Then in your view you could use the configuration string like this:

```
<h1 ng-controller="TestCtrl">Hello {{$eval(customer.name)}}!</h1>
```

It is important that your `customer.name` property does not contain the curly brackets!

See this plunkr for a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/r524cP6OAOBBzDReLNw4?p=preview

Comment: thanks. This is at least a more generic way to do this. The only "ugly" thing is that my string must already be an expression. Thanks this is a good workaround for me. I'd prefer a recursive evaluation of the curly brackets though. Would make life a lot easier!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 way to do it.

Create a directive that use a customer object and concatenate both First and Lastname.

```
angular.module('customer.directives',[]).
   .directive('customerName', function() {
      restrict : 'EA', // both element and attr will work in case you are using a customer directive
      replace : true,
      scope : {
          Customer : '='
      },
      template : '{{Customer.FirstName}}  {{Customer.Lastname}}'
 });
```

Example Call :

```
<div ng-repeat="Customer in Customers">
     <customer-name='Customer'></customer-name>
</div>
```

Or you could use a function inside the CustomerService to send your controller the full name already concatenated.

Ex :

```
angular.module('Customer.Services', [])
   .factory('CustomerService', function(){
      return {
         /* other methods here */
      getFullName : function(Customer) {
         return Customer.FirstName + ' ' + Customer.LastName
      }
    }
});



angular.module('Customer.Controllers', [])
    .controller('CustomerController', function($scope.CustomerService) {

        $scope.service = CustomerService.query();

        $scope.getFullName = fucntion(customer) {
            return CustomerService.getFullName(customer);
        }
    }
)
```

And call it with :

```
<div ng-repeat="Customer in Customers">
     {{getFullName(Customer)}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is not generic enough for me. I would not be able to just change my configuration to show Customer.Birthday. I'd have to create a directive and/or a function to be able to do that. I prefer Nikolas' workaround.